# Indefinite integral $\int x\sqrt{1+x}\mathrm{d}x$ using integration by parts

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$\int x\sqrt{1+x}\mathrm{d}x$$

$v'=\sqrt{1+x}$

$v=\frac{2}{3}(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}$

$u=x$

$u'=1$

$$\frac{2x}{3}(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\int\frac{2}{3}(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{2x}{3}(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{2}{3}*\frac{2}{5}(1+x)^{\frac{5}{2}}+c$$

result: $$\frac{2x}{3}(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{4}{15}(1+x)^{\frac{5}{2}}+c$$

Deriving: $$x(1+x)^\frac{1}{2}-\frac{20}{30}(1+x)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

Where did I get wrong?

Comment: Do you need it done by IBP?

Comment: @YagnaPatel yes

Comment: what are the bounds on the integral?

Comment: it is indefinite

Comment: Wolfram tells me [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=antiderivative+of+x*sqrt%281%2Bx%29) which at a glance doesn't seem incongruous with your answer.

Comment: I think IBP is only applicable to bounded integrals

Comment: @Alex: nooooooo

Comment: @gbox When in doubt, compute the derivative of the result. Assuming you don't get it wrong, if the derivative is the function you had to compute the integral of, you are correct.

Comment: Don't forget the constant of integration!

Comment: Except the constant of integration, OP's solution is good.

Comment: So I am doing something wrong with the derivative (updated)

Comment: @gbox Looks like you forgot to use the product rule when taking the derivative of the first term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're correct.**

> $u = x$, $dv=\sqrt{x+1}dx$ $\Rightarrow$ $v=\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2}$, $du=dx$.

&

> $$\int udv=uv-\int vdu$$

$$\Downarrow$$

**SOLUTION:**

$$\int x \sqrt{x+1}dx=x\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2}-\int\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2}dx=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{x\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2} -\frac{4}{15}(x+1)^{5/2}+C}$$

**VERIFICATION:**

Do not forget applying the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) when taking derivative.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(x\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2} -\frac{4}{15}(x+1)^{5/2}+C\bigg)=\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2}+x\sqrt{x+1}-\frac{2}{3}(x+1)^{3/2}+0=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #F0A]{x\sqrt{x+1}}$$

Comment: You got the same result as in the OP.

Comment: Sorry, I did not check carefully. Then OP is correct?

Comment: this pink boxes a burning my eyeballs